# Как подсчитать сумму прогрессивного налога?

Tags: javascript

> Создай функцию, которая рассчитывает сумму налогов исходя из объема доходов income. Используй 3-х ступенчатую модель налогообложения:
>
> часть income до 1000 облагается налогом 2%
> часть income от 1000 до 10000 - 3%
> всё что больше 10000 - 5%

Криво косо я уже решил первые 2 ступеньки, а вот в третьем условии ничего не происходит

```js
 function calculateTaxes(income) {
  if (income <= 1000) {
    return income * 0.02;
  }

  if (income > 1000) {
    return ((1000 * 0.02) + (income - 1000) * 0.03);
  }

  if(income > 10000) {
    return income * 100000;
  }
}
```

Comment: `return (income - 10000)*0.05 + 290`

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 собственно всё хорошо описано тут в примере многоступенчатой прогрессии (это как раз ваше условие)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то от введенной суммы нужно сначала взять 5%, пока сумма больше 10к, потом 3% пока сумма больше 1к и потом уже 2%. А не просто сделать проверку и если больше 10к, то такой процент, если больше 1к, то другой и тд

```
const calculateTaxes = income => {
  tax = 0;
  if (income >= 10000) {
    tax = Math.floor(income / 10000) * 10000 * 0.05;
    income = income % 10000;
  }
  if (income >= 1000) {
    tax = Math.floor(income / 1000) * 1000 * 0.03 + tax;
    income = income % 1000;
  }
  tax = income * 0.02 + tax;
  return tax;
}
```

Comment: Наиболее близкий к правильному ответ. Только прогрессивный налог считается не от всей суммы, а от превышения порога. Т.е. если я получаю 1200, то с 1000 я плачу 2%, а с (1200-1000)=200 3%. Итого 1000*2% + 200*3%=26

Comment: Пример на 3 %  calculateTaxes(10000) === 290;

taxes = 1000 * 0.02 + 9000 * 0.03 = 20 + 270 = 290;

Comment: @AlexeyTen я именно это и реализовал.

Comment: на 5%   сalculateTaxes(12000) === 390;

taxes = 1000 * 0.02 + 9000 * 0.03 + 2000 * 0.05 = 20 + 270 + 100 = 390;

Comment: @Gelloiss подставьте в вашу функцию 1200. В функции должны быть вычитания, а не деление с округлением

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h32s0u5z/ давайте проверим.
Вводим 12300. Сначала 5% от 10к - 500
Затем остается 2300. Берем 3% от 2к - это 60
Остается 300, от которых берем 2% и это будет 6. В сумме - 560

Comment: @AlexeyTen поставил. Получилось 34. 3% от 1000 = 30, 2% от 200 = 4. В сумме 34, все верно. Там нужно как раз деление, чтобы знать сколько целых тысяч или десять тысяч в вводимом числе. Например, число 29950. Там будет 2 целых 10 тысяч, 9 целых одна тысяча и остаток 950, от которого берем 2%

Comment: @Gelloiss см мой первый комментарий. Должно быть 26

Comment: @AlexeyTen Вы собственное условие перепутали. 1200 - от 1000 по вашему условию надо брать  3%, а от 200 - 2%. В первом комментарии вы пишите наоборот, от 1000 - 2%, а от 200 - 3%. Определитесь, пожалуйста)

Comment: А почему return только в одном учловии

Comment: И tax он тоже не находит. В следствии фэйлиться всё :(

Comment: @Gelloiss для  12300 5% берётся не от 10000, а от (12300-10000)=2300. См пример многоступенчатой прогрессии https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Я теряю веру в человечество и разработчиков. Каким местом неверная функция стала принятым ответом?

Comment: Неправильно. Подсказка, попробуйте объяснить, почему налог на 999 - 20, а на 1001 - 30 ;-)

Comment: @AlexeyTen Таким, что изначально Вы совершенно другое условие написали)

Comment: @Gelloiss я вообще никаких условий не писал.

Comment: @AlexeyTen извиняюсь, подумал Вы ТС

Comment: И все же ответ стоит привести к формулировке вопроса

Comment: `calculateTaxes(1000) === 30`, а правильный ответ `20`.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что второй if (и выход из функции) наступает раньше чем третий при значении income больше 10000:

```
function calculateTaxes(income) {
  if (income <= 1000 ) {
    return ...
  } else if (income > 10000) {
    return ...
  } else if (income > 1000) {
    return ...
  }
}
```

или

```
function calculateTaxes(income) {

  if (income <= 1000 ) {
    return ...
  } else if (income > 1000) {
    if (income > 10000) {
        return ...
    }
    return ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: Вы же условие задачи вообще не поняли

Comment: @Gelloiss изначально было сформулировано несколько по-другому

Answer (score 2):

У вас второй if выполняется всегда, когда income > 1000. Т.е и тогда когда income = 1000000. Задайте более жесткое условие income > 1000 && income <= 10000. Или поменяйте 2й и 3й местами

Answer (score 0):

```
С начала у меня била проблема с тем, что я росбирал проценты от всей суммы (income),
```

a нужно от каждой части брать свой процент

```
'use strict'

function calculateTaxes(income) {
  if (income <= 1000) {
    return income * 0.02;
  }

  if (income > 1000 && income <= 10000) {
    return 1000 * 0.02 + (income - 1000) * 0.03;
  }

   if (income > 10000) {
    return 1000 * 0.02 + 9000 * 0.03 + (income - 10000) * 0.05;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function calculateTaxes(income) {
  if (income <= 1000 ) {
    return income*0.02;
  } else if (income <= 10000) {
    return income*0.03;
  } else if (income > 10000) {
    return income *0.05;
  }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `calculateTaxes(1001) === 30.03`, а правильный ответ `20.03`.

Answer (score 0):

Уже ответили что второй условный оператор не даёт исполниться третьему. Налог по таблице удобно считать с больших сумм к меньшим. Сумма дохода разбивается на части и сумма налога накапливается по частям:

```
const calculateTax = income => {
    let tax = 0;
    if (income > 10000) {
        tax += 5 / 100 * (income - 10000); // 5% за доход больший 10000
        income = 10000;
    }
    if (income > 1000) {
        tax += 3 / 100 * (income - 1000); // 3% за доход больший 1000
        income = 1000;
    }
    tax += 2 / 100 * income; // 2% за оставшийся доход
    return tax;
};
```

В коде выше суммы порогов упоминаются многократно. Сам код "табличный" - можно переписать его в виде цикла:

```
const calculateTax = income => {
    // таблица налоговых ставок записывается по убыванию порогов
    const rates = [
        [10000, 5], // всё что больше 10000 - 5%
        [ 1000, 3], // часть дохода от 1000 до 10000 - 3%
        [    0, 2]  // часть дохода до 1000 облагается налогом 2%
    ];
    let tax = 0;
    for (const [threshold, rate] of rates) {
        if (income > threshold) {
            tax += rate / 100 * (income - threshold);
            income = threshold;
        }
    } 
    return tax;
};
```

Здесь уже дублирования кода и констант нет - меньше возможности совершить ошибку. Не очевидное требование к таблице налоговых ставок - она должна быть записана от больших порогов к меньшим.